# Error in crontab while try to save in CLI mode

Tags: linux, bash, cron, find

I am trying to add a commend in crontab so folder "XYZABC" delete if anyone makes in my server, and it should run every hour.

```
* 1 * * * *  /usr/bin/find /home/ -type d -name "XYZABC" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

When I try to save the above command it shows me an error

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.cc9iSz":23: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I don't know why you're getting this error, but check out [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#*_1_*_*_*) to debug your bad time spec

Comment: You have one time-spec (asterisk) too many.